# How to use XPathNavigator and return different nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML file like this:

```
<Document>
   <Tests>
      <Test>
         <Name>A</Name>
         <Value>0.01</Value>
         <Result>Pass</Result>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Name>A</Name>
         <Value>0.02</Value>
         <Result>Pass</Result>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Name>B</Name>
         <Value>1.01</Value>
         <Result>Fail</Result>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Name>B</Name>
         <Value>0.01</Value>
         <Result>Pass</Result>
      </Test>
   </Tests>
</Document>
```

And a class to hold data for each Test:

```
public class TestData
{
   public string TestName {get; set;}
   public int TestPositon {get; set;} //Position of Test node in XML file
   public string TestValue {get; set;}
   public string TestResult {get; set;}
}
```

Now I am using this code to put all Test's in a `List<TestData>`

```
doc = new XPathDocument(filePath);
nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

private List<TestData> GetAllTestData()    
 {


    List<TestData> Datas = new List<TestData>();
    TestData testData;

    XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select("/Document/Tests/Test/Name");

    int pos = 1;

    foreach(XPathNavigator val in it)
    {
       testData.TestPosition = pos;
       testData = new TestData();
       // This adds the Name, but what should I change to access Value and Result
       // in the same nav ??
       testData.TestName = val.Value; 
       Datas.Add(testData);
       pos++; //Increment Position
    }

    return Datas;
 }
```

So as I said in the comment, the XPath is only refering to `Name` node, how can I get all 3 nodes in a single foreach for the itterator? I mean how to assign this things aswell:

```
testData.Value = ???
testData.Result = ???
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use XPath

```
/Document/Tests/Test
```

It selects test nodes. Then in `foreach` use [`XPathNavigator.SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5htcxk90.aspx):

```
foreach (XPathNavigator val in it)
{
    testData = new TestData();
    testData.TestPosition = pos;
    testData.TestName = val.SelectSingleNode(nav.Compile("Name")).Value;
    testData.TestValue = val.SelectSingleNode(nav.Compile("Value")).Value;
    Datas.Add(testData);
    pos++;
}
```

Or use this XPath:

```
/Document/Tests/Test/*
```

It selects all nodes.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question. The reason I am usting navigator is that I want also the position of the node in XML file. will using your code takes care of positon as well? check my updated question please.

Comment: Can you tell please how should I define `/Document/Tests/Test` with XPATH?

Comment: @Sean87, In your code replace `/Document/Tests/Test/Name` with `/Document/Tests/Test`

Comment: I just wanted to ask, if there is a internal vay in Navigator that can return position of the node so I dont have to do it manually?

Comment: @Sean87, You can try `position()` XPath function. But I think your way is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
 XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select("/Document[Tests/Test/Name]");
```

this will return you all the document elements which has Tests/Test/Name inside them

now you can be sure that if you scan document - you will have the 3 leafs.